# How Do I Select The Last 5 Elements in Diffrent Array Length While Map With Css,Scss Or TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, css, typescript, sass, modulo

I have this code. This data array length is changing according to data. I want to make style for last remainder elements according to every array.length % 5 . But i cant find a solution with css.

```
<div className={styles.container}>
      {data?.cast.map((movie) => {
        const mod = data.cast.length%5     
        return (
          <div
            key={movie.id}
            className={styles.container_card}
            style={{ "--n": mod } as React.CSSProperties}
          >
            <MovieCard
              credit={movie}
              categoryType={keys}
              genreId={movie.genre_ids[0]}
            />
          </div>
        );
      })}
    </div>
```

I am using Scss. I am trying to write css like below.

```
.container {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  &_card {
    width: 20%;
    position: relative;
    &:hover:nth-last-child( array.length % 5  ) {
      transform: translateY(-200px);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Do you mean for the style to change for each movie in the array? Maybe change `map((movie) => ...` to `map((movie, index) => ...`, and compute `mod = (index % 5) + 1`

Comment: No I want to make style for last remainder elements according to every array.length % 5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the last n-items that represent the remainder you can do something like this:

```
// assuming you have a data structure like this
const data = {
  cast: ['p1', 'p2', 'p3', 'p4', 'p5', 'p6', 'p7', 'p8', 'p9', 'p10', 'p11', 'p12', 'p13', 'p15', 'p16', 'p17', 'p18', 'p19', 'p20']
};

// this will get you the last n-items that are the remainder items
const mapped = data.cast.map(movie => {
  const remainder = data.cast.length % 5;
  const lastItems = data.cast.slice(-remainder);
  console.log(lastItems); // prints: [ 'p17', 'p18', 'p19', 'p20' ]
});
```

So, now how do we apply this to the styling in CSS? You can either add a class to the `className` or use the `style` attribute in React.

The idea is that you only ever add this class or style, if the item that you are iterating over is in the list of the remainder items.

The following is just a simple example of how it could look like. This is not optimized, but you get the idea:

```
<div className={styles.container}>
      {data?.cast.map((movie) => {
        const remainder = data.cast.length % 5;
        const lastItems = data.cast.slice(-remainder);
        const remainderClass = lastItems.includes(movie) ? 'remainder-item' : '';
        return (
          <div
            key={movie.id}
            className={`${styles.container_card} ${remainderClass}`}
          >
            <MovieCard
              credit={movie}
              categoryType={keys}
              genreId={movie.genre_ids[0]}
            />
          </div>
        );
      })}
    </div>
```

The lastItems stay the same for each iteration so you could move this outside of the loop. Also, consider using `clx` or `classnames` npm packages. They are quite useful to toggle classes.